# How to display items from database one by one each time a button is clicked in php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Well, I'm having a page where I wanna display the items stored in the database one by one. One by one means on click of a button the next item should come.
(Items are the questions by the way in my case).

So I wrote the code for this. The problem I'm getting is that the loop is working only one time. I mean when the next button is clicked, I'm getting the next item displayed, but then I click Next again 'n nothing happens. Here's the code..

```
<?php

 $qno=1;

 require_once('connect.php');

  if(isset($_POST['next'])){
  $qno+=1;
  }

  $q="select * from `uquestion` where `qno`='$qno' and
  `uname`='{$_SESSION['user']}'";

 $result=mysqli_query($con,$q);

 if ($result) {

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
$qno = $row['qno'];
$question = $row['question'];
$op1 = $row['op1'];
$op2 = $row['op2'];
$op3 = $row['op3'];
$op4 = $row['op4'];
$answer = $row['answer'];

}
}
?>

<form name="exam" method="post" action="exam.php">
 <!--My Current page name is "exam.php" -->

<?php echo $question ?>  <br>

<input type="radio" name="question1" value="op1"> <?php echo $op1; ?> <br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="op2"> <?php echo $op2; ?> <br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="op1"> <?php echo $op3; ?> <br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="op1"> <?php echo $op4; ?> <br>
<input type="submit" name="previous" value="Previous">
<input type="submit" name="next" value="Next">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are setting the `$qno` to 1 every time you run the *exam.php* page.

So the first time you run your code, `$qno` will be 1 and because `$_POST['next']` is **not set**, *question number 1* will be shown. when you hit next, again `$qno` will become 1 again and this time because `$_POST['next']` is **set**, *question number 2* will be shown. and from now on, you will only see *question number 2*.

So one of your solutions is that you store your question number in a session variable. your code will be something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('connect.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION['qno']))
  $_SESSION['qno'] = 1;
else{
  if(isset($_POST['next'])){
    $_SESSION['qno'] += 1;
  }
}

$q="select * from `uquestion` where `qno`='".$_SESSION['qno']."' and `uname`='{$_SESSION['user']}'";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks bro..it worked.. Now i needed lill more help..say,for the 1st question the user selects option 2..now how to check if the user's choice is correct or not for this particular question comparing it with the correct answer stored in the database for that particular question.. thank you in advance..

Comment: it's easy, you are posting the answers every time user hits the next button. so after you check the session variable and before your `select` query, check `if(isset($_POST['next']))` it means the user have answered a question, then run an query and compare the user answer for the relevant question with the correct answer in the db. if your query returned any results, it means the answer was correct, if not, it means the answer was wrong. and be sure to use **mysqli prepared statement** to avoid `sql injection` by users. please do a research on it and come back if you had any questions on it.